# jquery url validation with particular content in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation to validate my form.
I have some url validation required for this

I have one field in which I want to validate url 
validation should be such that it should contain "phobos.apple.com, deimos3.apple.com, albert.apple.com, gs.apple.com, itunes.apple.com, ax.itunes.apple.com"

any of these url in it.

if the entered string contain any of above url than it must validate it.
using jquery validation or javascript.

Comment: I didn't anything in jquery validation

Comment: give in the code that you have so far tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the url with a regular expression like this:

```
function checkURLValue(url) {
    // this regex would not match a leading protocol which you actually should prepend..
    // you should definitely look for a better regular expression 
    var regEx = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9\\.]+\\.[a-z0-9]+$');

    if (regEx.test(url)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope this helps!